# java - send https request to server ip address throws SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, https

I need to send post request to server ip through `HTTPS` protocol. Here is my code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
String address = "https://100.100.100.100:90"; //just an example
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(address);
httpPost.addHeader("charset", "UTF-8");

//set post data(not important here)
...

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

the last line throws this exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
```

What's the problem and how can I solve this?

**EDIT:**

I don't know DNS name, so I need to use ip instead. I sent ajax request to that ip in browser, browser sends request, but requests stay in waiting mode. My Http Client is a simple java desktop application.

Comment: Why can't you connect by DNS name? Do you know the DNS name? What HTTP client are you using? What happens when you connect to that address using a browser?

Comment: Based on the code you have provided, it appears that your http client (httpClient) does not have the remote host's certificate (100.100.100.100) in its truststore. Until the client has the remote host's certificate in its truststore, you will be unable to connect using SSL/TLS (ie https)

Comment: If you try to use `https://100.100.100.100:90` address in browser (not AJAX but in URL bar), does it show any certificate info? The certificate should contain the hostname it is issued for.

Comment: I tried it in browser url bar, browsers stay in waiting mode and after some minutes, shows `problem loading page`.

Comment: I wouldn't have expected an SSL/TLS enabled server on port 90. This looks more like plain HTTP to me. Try to open a connection using telnet and see what happens.

Comment: @mangotang: you should normally not need the server's cert but rather the root/anchor for the CA that _issued_ the server cert; and more important that causes a local ValidatorException, NOT 'remote closed during handshake', (@Jiri) I concur 90 is usually HTTP not HTTPS; are you quite sure of that port number? If so, try either logging with sysprop `javax.net.debug=ssl` (and add to your Q) or a tool that logs in more detail like `openssl s_client -connect host:port -debug`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 from work I've done, unless the client has imported the server's certificate into its truststore, the client will not get past the SSL/TLS handshake (the introductory communication between client and server). The imported certificate can be the server's cert. or a certificate higher up the certificate chain.

Comment: @mangotang: a cert in the server's chain must _be present_ in the client's truststore. This is _normally_ done by the server getting its cert from a well-known CA like Verisign GoDaddy etc; about a hundred of those CAs are included in Java at install and don't require any import. If the server uses a less-known or unknown CA, you do need to import something, and it's usually best to import the CA root, once, which handles any number of servers. But more important, as I said, the exception _in this Q_ CANNOT be caused by the cert not validating.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the server you're trying to connect to doesn't accept requests using IP address.

In HTTP, this happens if the server is used for multiple domains / websites - it needs to know which one to give you and it does so based on the `Host` header. So if you want to connect by IP your client must be configured to send the correct `Host` (and must be able to do so).

Now in HTTPS protocol, on top of this the server also provides a server certificate during the handshake and this certificate is issued for a server hostname }likely a DNS name e.g. `example.com`) - again if you connect by IP and don't give your HTTP client any more info, the client cannot validate that the certifiate received from the server is issued for the correct hostname.

Comment: Right, what can I do now for solving this problem?

Comment: See my comment in your question - we need more info.

Comment: I edited my question and add additional information.

Comment: If the server provides a cert for the wrong hostname(s) (one cert _can_ cover more than one name, but doesn't always) the client will indeed complain but with a very different exception than here. However, if the server supports multiple hosts with multiple certs, and OP is using an older HttpClient and/or Java that doesn't support the TLS ServerNameIndication extension, the server can't determine which cert is correct and _might_ just close, although it's better practice for it to send an alert.